# Different results between qasm_simulator and quantum computer: how to normalize for only few states

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, error-correction

I recently started developing circuits with Qiskit. I made a 5 qubit circuit in which the fourth qubit at the end of execution must always have value 1:
[image: My circuit]
When I do the simulation with qasm everything is ok.
[image: qasm simulation] 
When I start the circuit on ibmq_essex I get results in which the value of fourth qubit is 0. 
[image: ibmq-essex execution]
I would like to eliminate from the results all the states that have the fourth qubit at 0 and normalize the circuit to eliminate the errors. How can I do?
I have already tried the following set of instructions with Ignis but as you can see from the graph I have not achieved a satisfactory result

```
from qiskit.ignis.mitigation.measurement import (complete_meas_cal, CompleteMeasFitter)

cal_circuits, state_labels = complete_meas_cal(qr = circuit.qregs[0], circlabel = 'measerrormitigationcal')
len(cal_circuits)
cal_job = execute(cal_circuits, backend = qcomp,shots = 1024, optimization_level = 3)
job_monitor(cal_job)
cal_results = cal_job.result()
plot_histogram(cal_results.get_counts(cal_circuits[5]))
meas_fitter = CompleteMeasFitter(cal_results, state_labels)
meas_filter = meas_fitter.filter
mitigated_results = meas_filter.apply(result)
device_counts = result.get_counts(circuit)
mitigated_counts = mitigated_results.get_counts(circuit)
plot_histogram([device_counts, mitigated_counts], legend=['noisy', 'mitigated'],figsize=(20,15))
```

[image: After Ignis mitigation error]

Comment: Hi, @Martina welcome to the Quantum Computing Stack Exchange. I just want to share some related questions: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10152/mitigating-the-noise-in-a-quantum-circuit/10155#10155

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/different-qft-results-when-using-simulator-or-quantum-machine/10203#10203

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9924/why-ibm-quantum-experience-is-giving-different-results-under-ibmq-qasm-simulator

Comment: Also, this Qiskit tutorial for Measurement Error Mitigation can be helpful: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/measurement-error-mitigation.html

Comment: Hi Davit!
Thanks a lot for the answers.
I followed the last tutorial. When I do the simulation of the error with qasm and the correction with Ignis I have no problem. I have problems when I have to mitigate the error on real hardware. I edited the previous post with the instructions I used. From the last histogram it will be clear that the mitigation has unfortunately not taken place correctly. I have tried with all three optimization levels without achieving the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the simulator and quantum hardware is something that can't be avoided, there must be a difference, because of noise. The one thing that I noticed from the histograms is that the state with maximum probability for simulator was '11000' and for quantum hardware, the state with maximum probability was '10000'. I think this difference is caused by the small shots number. I have run the same circuit on `ibmq_essex` with 8192 shots and here is what I obtained:

[image]

So shots number can help to improve the results. Measurement error mitigation will help a little bit to improve this result even farther, but maybe the final result will be still unsatisfactory. Also, I want to mention that CNOT gates are noisier then single-qubit gates and in the circuit, we have 4 CNOTs applied on the  `q[4]` qubit, so I guess this has its effect. If `q[4]` is always '1', then we can just replace CNOTs with X gates applied to the corresponding qubits: this will reduce errors as well. Moreover if `q[4]` is not linked with some `q[n]` qubit the quantum compiler will introduce SWAP gates to be able to apply CNOT between `q[4]` and `q[n]`. This means that we will have even more CNOTs in the circuit then we have introduced (for more about SWAP and connectivity I recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l06HATJAbdI&list=PLmRxgFnCIhaMgvot-Xuym_hn69lmzIokg&index=17)). Here is the connectivity of `ibmq_essex` taken from this [site](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/):

[image]

If our `q[4]` corresponds to 4th qubit in the picture (not sure about this) then I imagine that the quantum compiler will introduce a lot of SWAP gates and, thus, the error will increase just because of not optimally chosen qubit.

Here is the final circuit after `optimization_level=3` (Note how many CNOTs are there):

[image]

From here, if I am not mistaken, we can deduce that `q[4]` is the 3rd qubit from `ibmq_essex`.

Here is the code that I have used:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' 
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
qpu_backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_essex')

quantum_register = QuantumRegister(4, 'q')
ancillary_qubit = QuantumRegister(1, 'a')
classical_register = ClassicalRegister(5, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(quantum_register, ancillary_qubit, classical_register)

circuit.h(quantum_register)
circuit.u1(-0.0707, quantum_register[0])
circuit.u1(-0.134, quantum_register[1])
circuit.u1(-0.236, quantum_register[2])
circuit.u1(-0.314, quantum_register[3])

circuit.x(ancillary_qubit[0])
circuit.cx(ancillary_qubit[0], quantum_register[0])
circuit.cx(ancillary_qubit[0], quantum_register[1])
circuit.cx(ancillary_qubit[0], quantum_register[2])
circuit.cx(ancillary_qubit[0], quantum_register[3])

circuit.u1(0.385, quantum_register[0])
circuit.u1(0.605, quantum_register[1])
circuit.u1(1.02, quantum_register[2])
circuit.u1(1.884, quantum_register[3])
circuit.h(quantum_register)

circuit.measure(quantum_register[0], classical_register[0])
circuit.measure(quantum_register[1], classical_register[1])
circuit.measure(quantum_register[2], classical_register[2])
circuit.measure(quantum_register[3], classical_register[3])
circuit.measure(ancillary_qubit[0], classical_register[4])

qpu_result = execute(circuit, backend=qpu_backend, shots=8192, optimization_level=3).result().get_counts()

plot_histogram(qpu_result, legend=[qpu_backend],figsize=(10,5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! You have been very helpful and I understand everything you wrote to me. I don't really know how to thank you and you have clarified many doubts I had.

Comment: You're welcome @Martina :). Happy to help.